# Fast Matlab Matrix to Java List conversion

Tags: java, matlab

I must massage data in a matrix of type `131072x1 int32` into a Java `List<Integer>` in Matlab. So far, the only working conversion I've come up with is to roll through the values and directly add them to a LinkedList.

```
count = size(data_flattened, 1);
ll = java.util.LinkedList;
for i = 1:count
    ll.add(data_flattened(i));
end
```

Which is slow in the extreme (5 seconds). I've tried several formulations of converting first to a Java array and then to a `List` but I always end up with an array with 1 column and 131072 rows.

**I need a way of quickly assigning an N-by-1 Matlab matrix of int32s to a Java `List<Integer>` type.**

Comment: I am quoting Matlab Documentation "Pass Array of Objects
To call a method with an argument defined as java.lang.Object or an array of java.lang.Object, pass either a Java array or a MATLAB cell array. MATLAB automatically converts the cell array elements to their Java types. A Java array is an array returned from a Java constructor. You also can construct a Java array in MATLAB using the javaArray function." Link : https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-java-methods.html

This suggests helps you to get a  java array from there you can convert into a list

Comment: @KaranSharma I have done that. Auto-conversion creates a single-column many row array and the List created from it is the same. Even transposing the array doesn't help, it still creates a single element list with all the values in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Convert to a cell

I found one way of getting Matlab to behave the way I want is to convert the matrix to cells.

```
    cells = num2cell(data_flattened);        
    the_list = java.util.Arrays.asList(cells)
```

It is faster than rolling through the array and appending to the list, but it is still too slow. On average 0.25 seconds per conversion which is better but still too high.

## Java 8 Stream

After some research and testing implementing a function in Java to handle the conversion to from an `int[]` to a `List<Integer>` in reasonable time (0.001 seconds).

```
public static List<Integer> flatten(int[] arr) {
    return IntStream.of(arr).parallel().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

To use Java 8 you'll need to point your MATLAB_JAVA environment variable to the newer JRE. The location of your JRE can be found using `java_home` on a Mac.

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

Then in .bashrc or similar

```
export MATLAB_JAVA="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre"
```

Launching MATLAB from the terminal will now correctly pick up the new JRE.

In Matlab you can check your Java version

```
version -java
```

and then in Matlab

```
matlab_data_flattened = matlab_data(:);
java_list = com.my.package.ClassName.flatten(matlab_data_flattened);
```